# Best way to get many significant digits from user using ActionsOnGoogle and DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get users to read numbers to me that have many significant digits.  Like 5.2894837, but longer.

Using the sys.number entity works great, but my custom fulfillment only receives 15 significant digits.  (Side note: wish the docs would say something about this and you didn't need to self-discover)

My first though was, oh, I'll just look for a double or float entity.  Unfortunately, there is no such thing.  At least in the docs.

My second thought was to use the any entity.  Then in my fulfillment javascript handle anything that comes in not as a number.  This actually worked for me in the simulator (capping out around 90 digits/characters).  Both with typed input and spoken.

Unfortunately on a Google Home device the input always enters my fulfillment as undefined.  I can see this in the Google Cloud Function logs.  Is there a way for me to see the raw input through this kind of interaction, like I can see in the simulator?  Is there a reason the Home device might act differently than the simulator?  I can see in the logs the correct code is being used (meaning its not a delay in deployment issue), and this is a "production" interaction (not using my dev email and test device, but an end user using their device, which I have replicated).

One final related piece, when I use the number entity and a user says "two period four five six", the input is not recognized as a number.  Dot and point both work.  Feature suggestion: let the period be interpreted as decimal point for a number entity.

That is most of the information I have gathered manually through experimentation in an effort to capture long numbers, does anyone have experience getting very long numbers from users and can share some tips and best practices?  My next step might be to write my own parsing engine, that removes spaces that sometimes get in the numbers between users and my fulfillment, interpret dot/point/period and turn a long string from a user into a useable javascript number.

But, I feel like I am missing something obvious, so am asking the community.

Much appreciated.

Note: if you think entering 20 digits by voice is a bad experience, I assure you I have seen users giggling and enjoying the interaction, and wanting to know if they could go as high as 100 digits.

Comment: Found this which might be useful/related: https://discuss.api.ai/t/api-ai-limitations/4200/27

Comment: Thanks.  That link is helpful as it highlights the lack of concrete answers for questions like mine.  Hoping someone who knows, weighs in!